# Elastic search for batch update of old documents

Tags: elasticsearch

In my application, I am using Elasticsearch for indexing and searching of documents.As expected, documents have some fields.

Due to new requirements, users want those documents to have some more new fields. I can add new fields for newly created documents, but I also need to have old documents too to have these fields.

I am thinking of writing a framework which would accept  generic criteria to read old documents and update them. By generic criteria, I mean it must be able to accept any user defined condition to read older documents.

I am new to ES,and hence not sure if its feasible.

So I want to know whether it is feasible to write such a framework using Elastic search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide a custom document id, you can reindex your existing data with the update api (available also in the [upsert](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#upserts) mode). In this way you can update the documents adding the new fields when you re-import the old data.

It is important to provide a document id, otherwise it is impossible to add fields to the existing documents, since only insert are possible.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit what is a custom id?

Comment: For a custom id i mean an id provided by who is indexing the data, and not the auto-generated document id created by elastic.